# Passing JSON object to api

Tags: json, spring, rest, api, view

My application(String boot app) receives an input (json format) from another application via rest api.
I want to parse the json input received and then create a view.
How should i pass this json object from controller to view (jsp or html) so that it can be displayed to the users.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. If another application sends a request, this other application will also receive the response, and no-one else. If you want to show the object sent by the other application to users, you need to save the information somewhere, typically in a database.

Comment: So if i store the json object received in a file on the system and then create a method in the receiving application which will first read this object from the file and then parse it and create an html?

Comment: Sure, you can do that. But most applications store their information in a database, that can store a massive amount of data, in a structure, queryable way, and be used from multiple applications/servers. Maybe you don't need all of this, but you certainly need to learn how HTTP works.

Comment: Basically , my application will read and show the data (which is generated by another application) to users . I am now clear as in how it can be achieved. 1Step. the first app will make an rest api call and pass the data to my app which will first store this data (json object) in db. 2 Step. My application will have another request mapping which will read the data from db first and then pass it to jsp so that it can be displayed to the users. I mixed these two steps into one. I am very new to programming and hence trying to learn.